# Rules aren't working on emails contained in subfolders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I have a rule to send all email from Amazon to a folder with the same name.

I have noticed that this company is also sending me unwanted emails that are not able to be unsubscribed.  I have made a rule for the key words contained in these unwanted emails to be then moved to the trash.

For some reason this is not working.  Can you not run rules on subfolders with Office 365?  That is pretty dumb imo.

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done? You can use another rule to delete the items and set it to run before the rule you've already created. I believe that is how this system is designed to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's right, Outlook rules are applied immediately when messages are received, as such they apply to the Inbox only (or Sent Items where it's a send rule), not to the sub-folders*.

What you can do it change the order in which the rules are applied, as they're run top-down in the order listed. So in your case, you need to change the order so the first rule is the one looking for those keywords and deleting the unwanted messages, and then second rule is the one that moves the remaining messages to the subfolder.

You may also need to adjust the move to folder rule if your email is on 365, and these rules are in Outlook. That will be processed by the server, but the keyword one may show as "(client-only)", as it will rely on checking the message contents, and that can require Outlook. If so, if you add a keyword condition to the move to folder rule (eg it contains the word "amazon" in the body... which they all obviously will) that will force it to also be local, and then both will only be processed when Outlook is running, and in the correct order. I know that's an issue with Outlook/Exchange, but can't remember if the same issue applies if the rule is configured within the 365 web UI.

*Keep in mind Outlook doesn't magically know what is changing in every folder you have, in an 365/Exchange/IMAP setup it literally has to iterate through each folder in turn looking for changes (eg you've moved an email there, deleted an email, marked it for follow up etc) to determine whether there are changes that need to be sync'd back to the server. That's why if you have a LOT of folders you can see a delay in changes being sync'd. So also applying rules to subfolders would take ages.

Comment: Agree with Keith Langmead, Outlook rule can only be applied to the emails in Inbox folder.

Comment: Looks like I was the one that was dumb.  I didn't read that rules are applied from top-down.  That would make sense and it appears to be working now.

Comment: I'm glad your problem has been solved. Would you mind marking your reply as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.